# Advanced Router - Power networking

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, bittorrent

I'm considering upgrading my current DD-WRT micro equipped router to something more powerful. I am interested in a router than handle atleast double the amount of connections my router can currently (4096) to better handle BitTorrent traffic when it's maxing out my connection bandwidth (16mbps/2mbps). On top of that I would want to create a gigabit lan for streaming 1080P video throughout my home.

For this type of situation would a higher end consumer grade router be able to fit this bill with DD-WRT on it for tweaking settings, would I be better off looking at a commercial grade router, or what about building a linux machine to act as a router and use a switch in combination with that instead?

I'm looking for the most bang for my buck, since I'm sure that there are plenty of $1000+ commercial routers that could do everything I want but be overkill for my application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps look into [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.com/), [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/), [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/) or [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/home) - they are small router operating-systems, that run on regular (old/slow) PC hardware.

Any of these will handle a *lot* of connections, and can do pretty much anything you could wish from such a system (multi-connections with failover, QoS, intrusion detection, host/connection to VPNs etc etc)

Comment: Untangle looks very nice especially with the amount of work they've put into the UI instead of having to manipulate everything in .conf files etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find second-hand cisco routes on ebay?

A friend of mine used to find very good equipement sold there.

Just find a few models which meet your requirements and check their prices on ebay.

Comment: Do you or anyone have any opinions of the Cisco WRVS4400N, I attempted to find it's technical specifications on Cisco's website but couldn't so I sent them an email asking if it could support 20K connections.

Answer (score 1):

@dbr

I agree with your answer, and would also like to add to your list:

Untangled - http://www.untangle.com/home

Answer (score 0):

The connection limit can be easily increased on your current DD-WRT. Did this myself - works on my Linksys WRT54-GS.

If you like DD-WRT, you could use the x86-Version on a small PC hardware (like ASRock ION).

Comment: I already had increased it from the few 100 it is by factory to 4096.